# Is it possible to extract the current page number from the request URL in Django REST?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have a view:

```
class FooPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10

class FooView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
    pagination_class = FooPagination
    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.?) # page number?
```

In get_queryset is it possible to extract the current page number from the request URL in Django REST?  For example, as in the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/foo/?page=10
```

Comment: usually you can get at those with `request.GET` from inside a view ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
pagenum = self.request.query_params.get('page', None)
```

Comment: :) If it is the first page, then, self.request.query_params.get('page', None) return None. All other pages, it gets the correct page number.

Comment: right, if it's not specified, you can assume it's whatever the **default** you've set it to.

Comment: That's a nice solution!